# "Windows 7 backup utility" on Windows 10 looks for files in old user folders after changing it

Tags: backup, windows-10

Yesterday, in order to recover from the latest Insider build, I installed Windows again, keeping the old non-system and non-user files in my HDD but installing a fresh Windows copy. I set up a new user, but since I entered my Microsoft Online credentials, it created a "strange" user folder ("cm090" where my Microsoft account is "cm0901@mydomain.com". yes, the 1 was missing), I renamed my profile folder thanks to this tip:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/rename-user-account-folder-in-windows-10-preview/88033eca-6b32-47c5-90ac-a5e7af17d094?page=1&auth=1

Now my problem is that when I try to do scheduled backup, it ends with:

```
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Documents. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Music. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Pictures. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\AppData\Roaming. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\AppData\Local. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\AppData\LocalLow. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Contacts. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Desktop. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Downloads. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Favorites. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Links. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Saved Games. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
Problema durante il backup del file C:\Users\cm090\Searches. Errore: (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (0x80070003))
```

"Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato" means "Unable to find specified path" in Italian.

My backup options are all the standard options ("Let Windows decide") including a system image.

Is there a way to fix those links without manually specifying which folders to backup?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting my account and creating a new, offline one with the name I desired, than I linked the Microsoft Account in a second step. Now all the correct folders are backed up.